# How to generate a form to select a user using Autoform and Collection2 in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I want to be able to select several users from a list of users.

I am user `collection2`, `simple-schema` and `autoform`.

I'd like to generate a simple quickForm for doing this. Here's my simple-schema:

```
Schemas.Item = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
        max: 100
    },
    userIds: {
        type: [String],
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
    }
});
```

Looking at the [autoform docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#affieldinput), I noticed that I want to have a select view so I need to pass in options.

I'd like to be able to do this right in my schema!

```
    userIds: {
        type: [String],
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
        options: function() {
            // return users with {value:_id, label:username}
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, I'd have to generate a template with quickFormFields just to pass in the options.

Just to pile things on, there shouldn't be any duplicate userIds...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

Probably you have already found an answer, but maybe somebody will find it useful. I have lots of different things to specify once you select user, that's why my type for users is [Object]. In your case, you can modify that. The most important part is autoform.options method and seems to be the part you were looking for.

```
    users: {
        type: [Object]
    },
    "users.$.id": {
        // you can use your own type, e.g. SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id, as I am using custom Schema for accounts
        type:  Schemas.Account._id,
        label: 'Select user',
        autoform: {
            options: function () {
                var options = [];
                Meteor.users.find().forEach(function (element) {
                    options.push({
                        label: element.username, value: element._id
                    })
                });
                return options;
            }
        }
    }
```

Snippet above will give you the list of all the users so you can easily select them from dropdown list.

Remember to add appropriate publish method to make that working as without that you will always get only currently logged one.